# css different resolution em or px

Tags: css, screen-resolution

I have a designed a website.I am new to css, html, php so in css I have used all sizes in px. But when I change the screen resolution, webpage content is not proper, meaning its like:

When I zoom out this is the result how to handle this in css??
When I googled about same I found that instead of using px I should use em / %.

What is to be used?

1. em
2. px
3. %

for widths and heights.

**Edit1**

after **zoom out**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Websites having a **percent (%)** width for the main content area is **not adviced** because of the inconsistency. It's best to use a **pixel width** of about 960 pixels, maybe a bit less, for the whole website, so that it will work for all resolutions.

As for elements inside the main content area, it is better to use percent widths because it doesn't make sense to both with calculating the exact pixel values. The result is set fixed, because the thing that it's a percentage of parent's fixed width, as opposed to the monitor's resolution, which varies between users.

#### To sum up:

It is better to use a fixed width parent with a `wrap` of `960px` and use fluid (`%`) element widths inside the `wrap`.

#### Sample code:

To get started, you can use this sample code:

#### HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <!-- Other Elements -->
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
.wrap {margin: 0px auto; width: 960px;}
```

For more information, do check out this question on Programmers: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/135506/percent-or-pixels-html-css

Comment: Hi Praveen ..when i zoom in the images on top of background image go more right..actually which should come to left..

Comment: I liked your answer but now i dont know how do i implement it

Comment: praveen i have edited the question..the content and images should be in white background place

Comment: @pradnya Use the wrapper (`<div class="wrap">`) which I said, it would work just fine with the wrapper and inside that wrapper, give the percentage for all the elements. So that in any browser and in any monitor resolution, it will be fine. Use the CSS too! :) Let me know if you face any difficulties...

Comment: @pradnya In that case, there's a setting in wordpress admin. Do you have admin access?

Answer (score 4):

[**font-size:**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/font-size) The font-size CSS property specifies the size of the font. The font size may, in turn, change the size of other items, since it is used to compute the value of em and ex length units.

**Values**

> **xx-small, x-small, small, medium, large, x-large, xx-large**
>
> A set of absolute size keywords based on the user's default font size (which is medium). Similar to presentational HTML's  through  where the user's default font size is .

***larger, smaller***

> Larger or smaller than the parent element's font size, by roughly the ratio used to separate the absolute size keywords above.

**length**

> A positive length. When the units are specified in em or ex,  the size is defined relative to the size of the font on the parent element of the element in question. For example, 0.5em is half the font size of the parent of the current element.

**percentage**

> A positive percentage of the parent element's font size.
>
> It is best to avoid using values that are not relative to the user's default font size, such as lengths with units other than em or ex. However, if such values must be used, px are preferred over other units because their meaning does not vary depending on what the operating system thinks (generally incorrectly) the resolution of the monitor is.

**--- POSSIBLE APPROACHES ---**

**Keywords**

> Keywords are a good way to set the size of fonts on the web. By setting a keyword font size on the body element, you can set relative font-sizing everywhere else on the page, giving you the ability to easily scale the font up or down on the entire page accordingly.

**Pixels**

> Setting the font size in pixel values (px) is a good choice when you need pixel accuracy. A px value is static. This is an OS-independent and cross-browser way of literally telling the browsers to render the letters at exactly the number of pixels in height that you specified. The results may vary slightly across browsers, as they may use different algorithms to achieve a similar effect.
>
> Font sizing settings can also be used in combination. For example, if a parent element is set to 16px and its child element is set to larger, the child element displays larger than the parent element in the page.
>
> **Note:** Defining font sizes in pixel is not accessible, because the user cannot change the font size from the browser. (For example, users with limited vision may wish to set the font size much larger than the size chosen by a web designer.) Therefore, avoid using pixels for font sizes if you wish to create an inclusive design.

**Ems**

> Another way of setting the font size is with em values. The size of an em value is dynamic. When defining the font-size property, an em is equal to the size of the font that applies to the parent of the element in question. If you haven't set the font size anywhere on the page, then it is the browser default, which is probably 16px. So, by default 1em = 16px, and 2em = 32px. If you set a font-size of 20px on the body element, then 1em = 20px and 2em = 40px. Note that the value 2 is essentially a multiplier of the current em size.
>
> In order to calculate the em equivalent for any pixel value required, you can use this formula:
>
> em = desired element pixel value / parent element font-size in pixels
>   For example, suppose the font-size of the body of the page is set to 1em, with the browser standard of 1em = 16px; if the font-size you want is 12px, then you should specify 0.75em (because 12/16 = 0.75). Similarly, if you want a font size of 10px, then specify 0.625em (10/16 = 0.625); for 22px, specify 1.375em (22/16).
>
> A popular technique to use throughout the document is to set the the font-size of the body to 62.5% (that is 62.5% of the default of 16px), which equates to 10px, or 0.625em. Now you can set the font-size for any elements using em units, with an easy-to-remember conversion, by dividing the px value by 10. This way 6px = 0.6em, 8px = 0.8em, 12px = 1.2em, 14px = 1.4em, 16px = 1.6em. For example:

```
body {
  font-size: 62.5%; /* font-size 1em = 10px */
}
p {
  font-size: 1.6em; /* 1.6em = 16px */
}
```

> The em is a very useful unit in CSS, since it can adapt automatically to the font that the reader chooses to use.

Comment: I bookmarked this question entirely for this answer. Great explanation of EMs